# Specific web font stops showing when switching between tabs in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, render

I have Open Sans web font, I've noticed strange behavior in Google Chrome - when I'm switching between browser tabs - and then return to my site - I see standard (sans-serif) font instead of custom (Open Sans). if I mouse-over the broken text - it becomes Open Sans again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that has a fix scheduled for the next stable release (#33)

Source: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236298#c152